# Query mongodb for a specific date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've googled and googled this, and for the life of me I can't make it work...which I know I am just missing something totally simple, so I'm hoping someone here can save my sanity.

I have am trying to lookup a range of documents from a mongodb collection (using mongoose) based on a date range.

I have this code:

```
var startDate = new Date(req.query.startDate);
var stopDate = new Date(req.query.stopDate);

studentProgression.find({ $and: [ {'ACT_START': {$gte: startDate, $lte: stopDate} } ]})
```

But it doesn't return any documents.

The date in the MongoDb collection is stored as a string, and looks like this (for example):

**ACT_START: "25-MAY-20"**
a
I know I'm probaby tripping somewhere with the fact it's a string and not a date object in mongo, as I haven't had this issue before.  I'd rather not go through the collection and change all the string dates to actual date objects.

Is there anyway to do this lookup the way I've laid it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to change the format of your `ACT_START` field and cast it to a Date.

By doing `$gte` and/or `$lte` on a string field, mongo will compare the two strings based on their alphabetical order.

Comment: Is there a way to do this "on the fly" for each time I query?  I've never used aggregations before, is this something that would do that?  Or is it better to just change it in the collection once and move on with life?  It's at about 500,000 documents and counting right now.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with aggregation. The first part will change the type of your field, and the second will match your documents with `$gte` and `$lte`. But if it's a query that you run quite often, or if you want to sort by date. I recommend you to change your field once, because it will be more performant. And it will be more advantageous as your collection will keep growing, But if you run a few of these queries, aggregation is the best and easiest thing to do here.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback.  I will likely just changed the format of the date and move on with life.  Cheers!